# How and where to set description of a cq5 site?

Tags: adobe, aem

The meta description that we get from a google search etc. 
Do we set the meta information from cq side?

Answer (score 0):

You usually set this in your base page template or which ever template your site is using to create pages.
You typically inherit from foundation/components/page and make suitable modifications to your page component(sling:resourceType of the template) depending on your requirement. You then override head.jsp to include your site specific meta tags.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we set all that information for each page in CQ page properties.

1. Go to siteadmin - http://localhost:4502/siteadmin
2. Navigate to the page on the left side of siteadmin so that you see the desired page on the right section of the page.
3. Right click on Page for which you want to set the meta information and then click on Properties.
4. In the dialog box that is opened, you can set all the meta information like Title, Keywords, Subtitle, Description in the first tab - Basic.
5. Save the dialog box by clicking on OK.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: @vinuthnapadma Please accept any one of the answers for this question.